# Python cross-module globale variable

Tags: python, nose, python-import

I'm new to Python and I was trying out nose as a unit test framework.
I came across a behavior I didn't expect, but maybe this is normal, hence my question.

I have two (very basic) files:

__init__.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
glob = 0

def setup():
    global glob
    glob = 42
    print "Package setup"
```

test_mymod.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from unittest import TestCase
from . import glob

print "test_mymod.py"

class testMyMod(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print glob

    def test_random(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        pass
```

Running `nosetest -s` gives me following output:

```
test_mymod.py
Package setup
0
```

Since the setup() function of the package is invoked before the setUp() function of the test, I expected to see `print glob` to output `42`.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there no way of doing what I want?
It seems to me that importing a variable copies its value instead of referencing it, but maybe there is way to do otherwise?

Thank you

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers, although you could fake it by having a mutable object that you mutate instead of reassigning a global name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `from . import glob` at the top of your test file, you get a reference to the value of `glob` in your namespace. This happens before you call `setup()`. When you call `setup()` the value of `glob` is updated in the `__init__.py` namespace but not `test_mymod.py`. Instead of importing `glob` directly, reference it like `package.glob`. Alternatively, set `glob` to its correct value at package import time; having unitialized globals that people can import is considered bad practice for exactly this reason.

Comment: Note though that "the value of `glob`" is a reference. You get two variables referencing the same object. If you had a mutable object instead of 0, you could observe that by mutating that object.

Comment: True, though in the case of an immutable value like an integer, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However, I can't find a way to "reference it like package.glob". Both files are in the same folder. How can I do that?

Comment: Surely the folder has some name, though. Then it is a package. Specifically if the name of the folder is ```foo```. You can do ```import foo```, and ```foo.glob```.